# incoming call ring volume ( sound - silent - vibrate )

Tags: volume-control

I used to be able to change the incoming call ring volume from **sound** to **silent** to **vibrate** using the volume buttons. Today I went to Sound settings and unticked "Audible touch tones" and since that I cannot use  the silence mode. Only volume or vibrate is available.

any idea how to make it back to **sound <-> silent <-> vibrate**

---

HTC Desire on CM7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the Audible Touch Tones menu item is actually related, since that controls whether or not you hear dial pad tones when dialing a number.

The setting you want should be `CyanogenMod Settings->Sound->Silent State`, and you'll just need to make sure that it's checked. I have Audible Touch Tones disabled as well, but it doesn't interfere with my ability to enable/disable the Silent State option.

Comment: I thought that Audible Touch Tones won't matter but I wanted to state what I did.

Comment: any way to change the order? Right now I have sound - vibrate - silence. It used to be sound - silence - vibrate

Comment: @Radek: Hm, that one I don't know. It's always been `Sound<->Vibrate<->Silent` for me, as far as I recall. I don't see any obvious way to change that order, either.

Comment: it's not necessary to change the order. I am happy as I have my 'silent' mode ... but you know humans ... they don't want any change :-p

Comment: @Radek: Oh yeah, I can understand that. I use a theme on Firefox 3.6 that basically makes it look like 1.5 ;)